# How to connect to the bluetooth server and discover a service?

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

I cant connect to my bluetooth server, set up on rpi. I would need a connectionUrl, presumably fetched from a ServiceRecord. But I cant seem to get it to work.

Ive set it up using bluecove, and have a server running, discoverable. However, I cant find any services on the device. 
The server:

```
UUID uuid = new UUID("446118f08b1e11e29e960800200c9a66", false);
String connectionString = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid + ";name=Mine";
StreamConnectionNotifier streamConnNotifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier) Connector.open(connectionString);
```

The client:

```
UUID[] uuidSet = new UUID[1];
uuidSet[0] = new UUID("446118f08b1e11e29e960800200c9a66", false);
agent.searchServices(null, uuidSet, remoteDevice, client);

public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord) {
System.out.println("service discovered");
```

But no service discovered. If I, in the server, do the following:

```
ServiceRecord sr = local.getRecord(streamConnNotifier);
System.out.println(sr);
```

..among other things, I see:

```
0x1:
    DATSEQ {
UUID 446118f08b1e11e29e960800200c9a66
UUID 0000110100001000800000805f9b34fb
}
```

I would guess that I could connect to the service via url 
btspp://b827ebe97e0e:446118f08b1e11e29e960800200c9a66, but I cant, I get `IllegalArgumentException: channel 446118f08b1e11e29e960800200c9a66`

Answer (score 0):

Anyone? Im using java, and the server is set up on Raspberry pi, and the client is my macbook laptop.

Am I correct to use the UUID as "port" (if we were talking http)?

Comment: My experience on bluetooth: *Those who know do not talk. Those who talk do not know.*